# Compactness of solution space of semi-linear parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, compactness, compact-operators

Under what conditions a closed and bounded subset of solution space of following parabolic PDE is compact?

$$x_{t}=x_{zz}+f(x,z)$$

Thank you!

Comment: I made a minor edit to your post so the $\LaTeX$ would render properly.  Surround $\LaTeX$ by "\$" signs or double "\$" signs to effect this.  See the MathJax tutorials.  Cheers!

Comment: Compact on what spaces? For instance if $f$ is bounded then any $L^\infty$-bounded sequence of solutions has a convergent subsequence in the space $C^1_{loc}$.

Comment: My space of interest would be $L^{2}$. What do you mean by $C^{1}_{loc}$? I presume it is space of continuous functions with continuous first derivative which are also $L^{2}$. Could you give some kind of proof and/or a good reference? Thank you.